# Publish a public branch on GitHub, without commit history, with the ability to merge in the future

Tags: git, git-merge

I've seen questions like this, but have not been able to find an answer. The first part seems to be easy, the second one, not so much.

I have a project on a private Git that has one branch, "master". I want to publish this master branch to a public Github server, but I do not want to include the commit history.

I did that like this, while on the master branch, on the command line I did this:

```
git remote add public git@github.com:name/repo.git
git checkout -b main
git rebase -i --root
```

Then squashed all but the first commit, finished the rebase and:

```
git push --set-upstream public main
```

This works in that it creates, on GitHub, a "main" branch, with only that branch. But, when I want to merge further work from master to the main branch, I keep getting the unrelated history error

```
git merge master
refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Is this something that can actually be done, in summary:

- Do work on master branch on private repo
- Periodically push work to main branch on public repo, without commit history

Comment: Sure. You just have to continually update that public commit with the new changes. You can’t merge between them (you can but it won’t have a purpose).